# Import single csv file with one data field going to separate table

Tags: python, csv, import

I have a csv file containing a list of `Products` with the following 4 fields

```
Product ID, Name, Alias, UOM
```

I would like to import the file into a database that has 2 tables. The first is the `Product` table:

```
Product ID, Name, UOM
```

The second is the `Product Alias` table:

```
Product ID, Alias
```

Each `Product ID` may have 0 to many alias names.

Is there any way I could treat the `Alias` column different by the fact it has a different separator between the commas, like ";" or a period "." to separate the 0 to many alias names for a given Product ID?

Therefore during the csv import, when it gets the 3rd comma, it would import that data into the 2nd table but import a new record with repeating Product ID's for as many alias names are in that comma field.

Hopefully I explained that well enough, let me if I didn't.  I'm more interested in the possible processing of doing this regardless of what code that is being using but python would be the preferred route.

**Example data**

```
ProductID, Name,    Alias, UOM
122,       Widget1, W1;    Wid1;Wt1, Each
123,       Widget2, ,      Each
124,       Widget3, W3;    Wt3, Each
```

Comment: As a side note, with the default arguments, `csv.reader` or `DictReader` will preserve the leading spaces on these fields—e.g., the Name in the first row will be `" Widget1"`, not `"Widget1"`. Usually `skipinitialspace=True` solves that problem… but if you're generating the CSV, it's better to generate it in a more Excel-ish format without those spaces and/or use quoting, unless it's important that the CSV files be human-readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do.

First, you use `csv` as usual to get all the columns. One of those columns will itself be a semicolon-separated list of values.

If you don't need to worry about quoting, etc., you can just use `split`. For example:

```
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Product (ProductID, Name, UOM) 
                          VALUES (:ProductID, :Name, :UOM)''', row)
        for alias in row['Alias'].split(';'):
            cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO ProductAlias (Name, Alias) 
                              VALUES (?, ?)''', row['Name'], alias)
```

If you can have spaces within the aliases, you're going to need two kinds of quoting or escaping, alongside the two kinds of delimiters. Like this:

```
123,"Widget 1","Widget1;W1;Wid1;Wt1;'W 1'",Each
```

And you'd want to parse it by using another `csv.reader`. Of course `csv` is intended to parse a sequence of lines into a sequence of rows, not a single line into a single row, but that's easy to deal with by just wrapping the single line in a list, and extracting the single row from the result. For example, instead of this:

```
row['Alias'].split(';')
```

… do this:

```
next(csv.reader([row['Alias']], delimiter=";", quotechar="'"))
```

(Although you'd probably want to split up the expression into multiple steps once it gets this complicated.)